# Does React Native's FlatList allow you to position the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollbar, react-native-flatlist

I currently have FlatList implemented within a project, and I need to either move the scrollbar further down so that it does not run over some of the items in the FlatList, or I can just remove the scroll bar altogether. I was curious as to whether or not positioning the scrollbar is doable. I'm assuming that I could set the prop of `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` to false within the FlatList if I wanted to just get rid of it as well.

I've tried to adjust the container's padding and margins to see if that would push the scrollbar away, but it does not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS, you can set `scrollIndicatorInsets` of any `ScrollView`, including `FlatList` to set insets of the scroll indicator. For Android, there's no way to set the insets for now.

See the doc for `scrollIndicatorInsets`: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollindicatorinsets